# react -- Empty post body

Tags: reactjs, http

I use react as my web's frontend, and go as my web's backend. My post sentences are:

```
fetch(MYURL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
```

But my backend program receives empty body.

My browser shows that the request payload is not empty, but when I use wireshark to capture the http packet, the content-length is 0 and the body is empty.

Comment: What does `data` look like (or at least what type is it)? Also can you share the relevant server-side code?